# Wordpress Cron doesn't fire wp_mail() but php mail() function

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I´m trying to use wp_mail in cronjob task, but no email was sent. Instead pure php function mail() works.

Question 1): Why does mail() work but wp_mail doesn't?

Question 2): Calling www.domain.de/wp-cron.php manually fires the email. But the html email body of the received email is still a string and not translated to html. Do you know why?

Searched for solutions, found some. According to this post ([Cron job in WordPress not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752854/cron-job-in-wordpress-not-working)), I setup my cronjob like this:

Setup a custom interval:

```
function example_add_cron_interval( $schedules ) {
$schedules['five_seconds'] = array(
    'interval' => 5,
    'display'  => esc_html__( 'Every Five Seconds' ),
);
$schedules['daily'] = array(
    'display' => esc_html__( 'Once Daily' ) 
);
return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'example_add_cron_interval', 999 );
```

activate cronjob:

```
function cron_activation() {
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'dbs_cron_hook' ) ) {  
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'dbs_cron_hook' );  
    }
}
add_action('init', 'cron_activation');
```

Do logic:
    function my_task_function() {

```
$max_hours = 336; // entspricht 2 Wochen
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'bookings', );
$booking_listing = new WP_Query( $args );
$mail_body = '<table>';

if( $booking_listing->have_posts() ) :
    while( $booking_listing->have_posts() ) : $booking_listing->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $email_sent_timestamp = intval( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'approvement_email_sent', true ) );
        $event_id = intval( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'event_id', true ) );

        if( $email_sent_timestamp != 0 ){

            $date = date_create();
            $now_timestamp = date_timestamp_get($date);
            $hoursPassed = diff_timestamp( $now_timestamp, $email_sent_timestamp );

            var_dump($hoursPassed["full_hours"] >= $max_hours);

            if( $hoursPassed >=  $max_hours ){

                update_post_meta( $event_id, 'event_reserved', intval(0) );
                $mail_body .= '<tr><td>BuchungsNr ' . $post_id . ': 2 Wochen sind abgelaufen.</td></tr><tr><td>Der Termin ' . $event_id . ' wurde wieder aktiviert.</td></tr>';

            }
        }

    endwhile;
else:
    wp_send_json_error( "No events found" );
endif;

$mail_body .= '</table>';

var_dump($max_hours);

// wp_mail( 'xxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx', 'Rervierung ' . $post_id . ' abgelaufen', $mail_body );

mail( 'xxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx', 'Rervierung ' . $post_id . ' abgelaufen', $mail_body );

}
add_action( 'dbs_cron_hook', 'my_task_function' );
```

I disabled wp cron in config.php like this
`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

And setup a system cronjob on the server like this `* */1 * * * /vrmd/webserver/php70/bin/php-cli /homepages/xxxxxx/wp-cron.php > /dev/null`

Hope you can help me.

EDIT to Question 2: just use $headers in mail() function

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
mail( $to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers );
```

Question 1 still wondering...

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses a pseudo-cron system `wp-cron.php` to handle scheduled tasks, and this includes sending emails triggered by events or scheduled tasks

You can add the following line to your wp-config.php file to force a real cron job to run instead of relying on web requests.

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

simple running script

```
  add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_every_per_five_second' );
        function isa_add_every_per_five_second( $schedules ) {
            $schedules['every_per_day'] = array(
                    'interval'  => 5,                    
                    'display'   => __( 'Every 5 Seconds', 'textdomain' )
            );
            return $schedules;
        }
        
        // Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'isa_add_every_per_five_second' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_five_seconds', 'isa_add_every_per_five_second' );
        }
        
        // Hook into that action that'll fire every five seconds
        add_action( 'isa_add_every_per_five_second', 'every_five_seconds_event_func' );
        
        function every_five_seconds_event_func() {
        
        $to = 'sendto@example.com';
        $subject = 'The subject';
        $body = 'The email body content';
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
        
 }
```